# Inconsistent SQLite3 insert from Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, newline

I have an issue inserting values into SQLite3 database from Python. The following code inserts the new line differently.

```
m.execute("INSERT INTO transactions VALUES "+str((timestamp,address,recipient_input,amount_input,signature_enc,public_key_readable,openfield_input))+"")

m.execute("INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('" + str(timestamp) + "','" + str(address) + "','" + str(recipient_input) + "','" + str(amount_input) + "','" + str(signature_enc) + "','" + str(public_key_readable) + "','" +str(openfield_input) + "')")
```

The second example inserts new lines properly into the SQLite database, the first one inserts "\n" symbol. Is there any explanation for that? I would like to use the first model using tuples, but without replacing the new lines with "\n" symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str()` formats its argument according to the Python syntax rules, so it is never appropriate for SQL.

To prevent formatting problems (and SQL injection attacks), use parameters:

```
m.execute("INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
          (timestamp, address, recipient_input, amount_input,
           signature_enc, public_key_readable, openfield_input))
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to look at how a tuple is printed if it contains a string with a newline to see the difference:

```
>>> print(("foo\nbar",))
('foo\nbar',)
>>> print("foo\nbar")
foo
bar
```

So we see in one case, the string will be formatted with a '\n' whereas in the other case it will have a newline.

With that said, this is unlikely to be the right approach anyway.  You've opened yourself up to SQL injection.  You're better off:

```
values = (
    timestamp,
    address,
    recipient_input,
    amount_input,
    signature_enc,
    public_key_readable,
    openfield_input,
)
m.execute("INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values)
```